# HttpWebRequest.ContinueTimeout - что за свойство?

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Интересует свойство класса HttpWebRequest `HttpWebRequest` под названием ContinueTimeout, `ContinueTimeout`, для чего оно и как оно работает? Спасибо.

Comment: По какой причине вопрос должен быть удален?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ответ неожиданно обнаруживается... [на соответствующей странице MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.continuetimeout.aspx)!

P.S. Предвидя следующий вопрос: [HTTP 100 (continue)](http://httpstatusdogs.com/100-continue)

Comment: Ну так написано же! `Gets or sets a timeout, in seconds, to wait for the server status after 100-continue is received.`

В то время как Timeout: `Gets or sets the time-out value in milliseconds for the GetResponse and GetRequestStream methods.`